# How can I copy(gettext) from 50% of the textview?

Tags: android, textview, copy, partial

Maybe this is too easy, but I can't find the solution..

For example I can copy from TextView1 with this basic code.

```
TextView2.setText(TextView1.getText);
```

I am trying to this;

How can I copy first 50% of the TextView1's text.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: what do you mean by 50% ?

Comment: from length of TextView' s text. For example: if TextView ="abcdef", I want to "abc"

Comment: TextView1.getText.substring(0,TextView1.getText().length/2);

Comment: does it means if there is "Hello" in the textbox, then you want to copy "Hel" ?

Comment: Question is not about `TextView` its about String . [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class already has built-in methods for partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Use [**`substring()`**](https://www.javatpoint.com/substring)

```
TextView2.setText(TextView1.getText().toString().substring(0,TextView1.getText().toString().length()/2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextView2.setText(TextView1.getText().subSequence(0, TextView1.getText().length()/2));
```